# Github action react js project build problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, build, github-actions

I have a project in `react js` on `github`, when a commit is done it should do the build, then upload the build files to another `branch`.

But it's no longer working properly, can you give me a hand?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: subFormat@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.8.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.8.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.5.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"^5.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@mui/icons-material)
npm ERR!     1 more (@emotion/styled)
npm ERR!   1 more (@emotion/styled)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/material@5.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"^5.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!     @mui/icons-material@"^5.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/runner/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-03-15T22_14_24_928Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Action github

```yaml
name: Build and Deploy
on: [push]
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.1

      - name: Install and Build  # This example project is built using npm and outputs the result to the 'build' folder. Replace with the commands required to build your project, or remove this step entirely if your site is pre-built.
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.5
        with:
          branch: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to.
          folder: docs # The folder the action should deploy.
```

package.json

```js
"scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts build && cp -R ./copy-build/. ./build && rm -rf docs && mv build docs",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/main.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/main.css",
    "move-static": "cp -a ./node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/. public/webviewer/lib"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

if the error ocurred when you gave an `npm install <dependencyname>` command or just `npm install`, then run `npm install <dependencyname> --force` or `npm install --force`

Comment: They don't work, I also tried with `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps`